# Деление временного интервала Period

Tags: java

Подскажите пожалуйста, имеется временной интервал, например

```
Period period = Period.of(5,3,15);
```

К указанному периоду необходимо применить коэффициент 0.5,
Т.е разделить пополам, как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Этого сделать в общем случае просто так нельзя, т.к. решение зависит от начальной даты. Если она известна, то рассчитайте DAYS.between для пары стартовая дата - дата+период, поделите пополам, и дальше понятно, что делать.